# Excel Multiple rows to multiple columns for different values

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to produce something like discussed here ([Transpose multiple rows to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097773/transpose-multiple-rows-to-multiple-columns))
Basically

I got data in Excel or MS-Access like as follows

```
ID   Desc Day1 Day2 Day3 ...
London  Apr17  12 34  36  
London  May17  16 0   29
London  Jun17  17 18  43
Birm    May17  11 0   28
Birm    Jun17  12 18  42
```

I want to produce something like either in Excel or MS-Access

```
          --Apr---------   -----May ---------  -----------Jun----- 
ID      Desc Day1 Day2 Day3   Day1  Day2 Day3     Day1  Day2 Day3 
London Apr17  12 34  36      ...16  0   29        17   18   43
Birm                         ...11  0   28        12   18   42
```

Any ideas how this can be done

Did tried transpose , indirect etc
for me the challenge is I got around 10 columns remains same in beginning then about 10 columns on right hand side remain same and want around 400 columns for every day with calculated columns to be stored.

Comment: Can't have 400 columns in Access - tables and queries are limited to 255.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to do something like this in Excel I generally use a combination of formulas to create text cell references and then use the indirect function to grab the value. If your data is fairly uniform, then the formula to create the cell reference for the indirect function is fairly simple. If the data is not uniform, then a combination of match functions are needed to create the cell reference, and they get rather clumsy really quickly the more data that you have.

For example, if the first set of data shown starts in A1, and the second set of data starts in I1, then a formula such as:

=CHAR(CODE("J")+MATCH($B2,$J$10:$R$10,0)+MATCH(C$1,$J$2:$R$2,0)-2)&TEXT(MATCH($A2,$I$3:$I$9,0)+2,"#")

Note that I had to create a set of formulas in J10 through R10 that contained the correspond month Desc entry.

Now, this formula gets you a cell reference to where the data should go. The problem is that you need a reference from where the data should go, to where it is. So this is backwards. Here's where it gets cumbersome. You need another set of MATCH functions in a nested IF to get this:

=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(J11,$C$36:$C$42,0))),"C"&TEXT(MATCH(J11,$C$36:$C$42,0)+1,"#"),IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(J11,$D$36:$D$42,0))),"D"&TEXT(MATCH(J11,$D$36:$D$42,0)+2,"#"),IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(J11,$E$36:$E$42,0))),"E"&TEXT(MATCH(J11,$E$36:$E$42,0)+2,"#"),"I1")))

which gets brutal as you add more Day columns. Note that I had to create an array that contained the location text values in J11 through R13, which will need to be bigger with more data, although you could use a combination of ROW and COL functions instead of an array.

Then in J3 through R9 (expanded as more data is needed), the INDIRECT functions are used to select the data from the second IF/MATCH/MATCH function.

You can eliminate some of the secondary calculation cells, e.g. putting the IF/MATCH/MATCH/... function directly in the INDIRECT function, I find it easier when developing something like this to create a bunch of intermediate formula cells which help determine where something isn't correct, and there almost always is something messed up somewhere.

In Access, you could use a number of crosstab queries combined together in another query to make a big multi column data output. As someone else noted, ther emay be limitations on the number of output columns, I haven't tried it to see.

Good luck!